# Elmah works in MVC but not in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I have ELMAH working web app side controllers but I can not get exceptions logged in the Web API side.

My Setup:

WebApiConfig.cs:

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Web Config:

```xml
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>
....
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
</appSettings>
....
<modules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
....
<httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>
....
<elmah>
    <errorMail key="elmahMail" from="noreply@mydomain.com" to="me@mydomain.com" cc="" subject="DEV EMP Exception" async="true" smtpPort="25" smtpServer="smtp.mydomain.com" userName="" password="" />
</elmah>
```

I have tried with this on and off:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute());
```

Normally installing the Elmah.Mvc package and the Elmah.Contrib.WebApi packages plus adding the:

```cs
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
```

line turns on Elmah for the Web API just fine but it is no longer working.

Comment: As long as you've installed Elmah.Contrib.WebApi too, your config looks fine. Can you put your project somewhere where I can try it myself?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post my project.

Comment: Maybe try to recreate in a blank project and upload that?

Comment: I solved it. The answer was it was working the whole time. Elmah used to be triggered on a 404. This is no longer the case. I was testing by trying a route that did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was it was working the whole time. Elmah used to be triggered on a 404. This is no longer the case. I was testing by trying a route that did not exist.